# Time Series Forecasting in Python Without Weekends

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, forecasting, arima

I am trying to create a time series forecasting model in Python that predicts the number of help desk tickets in future dates but I noticed that the number of tickets each day fluctuate all the way to zero because of the weekends.

How do I account for this in Python using the ARIMA model? Here is my code:

```
#convert all the values to Date format
for i in range(len(df.submitdate)):
    df.submitdate.iloc[i]=dt.datetime.strptime(df.submitdate.iloc[i], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df.head()

#Adding a new column which will have the number odatf tickets per day
df['totalincidents']=df.groupby('submitdate')['incidentnumber'].transform('count')

#remove incident number from dataframe and drop duplicates
df.drop(['incidentnumber'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

df2=df

#settintg date as the index
df2=df2.set_index('submitdate')
df2.index=pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
df2.index
print(df2.head())

submitdate
2019-10-02    1101
2019-10-03    1027
2019-10-04    1350
2019-10-05      45
2019-10-06      85

2020-08-26    1773
2020-08-27    1294
2020-08-28    1336
2020-08-29     586
2020-08-30      20
Name: totalincidents, Length: 334, dtype: int64

df2.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

[Incidents over Time graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWT6Q.png)

Comment: Why dont you filter out weekends from your dataframe so you have a series that can be managed.

Comment: I am trying to predict the number of help desk tickets in future dates. If I am trying to forecast a month out, how should I account for weekends?

Comment: @cbuzz I see two options: You can either include a seasonal (weekly) part to capture a weekly periodicity; or include the day of the week as an external regressor (using dummy encoding). If I were you, I'd start with the second approach. Forecasting would then be straightforward: The only thing you'd need to provide is the day of the week for the forecast horizon.

Comment: PS. It's best to provide minimal sample data so that we have something to work with. Otherwise, showing code is not very meaningful.